# Saving Image on Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want to upload an Image to parse.com. I choose the Image from gallery and place it in an ImageView in Activity A as follows:

```
addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}
};
```

Then, In OnActivityforResult:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
             mMediaUri = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(mMediaUri,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

           // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            propertyImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

        }
```

Then I send the byte array through Intent:

```
intent.putExtra("Image",byteArray);
```

Now in Activity B:

```
byte[] data = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("Image");


        final ParseFile file = new ParseFile("propic.png", data);
        file.saveInBackground();
```

Finally I send it to parse like:

```
listedProperty.put("PropPic", file);
```

Since then, data is not getting into my parse class and I am getting an unsuccessful callback from parse. What could be wrong?

LogCat:

```
03-14 04:14:23.987    1688-1688/com.iwillcode.realestate I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-14 04:14:25.808    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:25.808    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa24751e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:14:34.204    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:34.204    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2426fc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:14:35.624    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:35.624    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2475a20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:14:37.224    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:37.224    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2b0b140, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:14:39.432    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:39.432    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2426060, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:14:46.229    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:46.229    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2475e20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:14:51.681    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:51.681    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa2b18f20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:14:53.801    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:53.801    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xacf8fde0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:14:55.425    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 04:14:55.425    1688-1717/com.iwillcode.realestate W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa0f727e0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-14 04:15:03.226    1688-1688/com.iwillcode.realestate E/No﹕ Unseccessfull
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat? That might provide some clues...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps but I save my bitmapped images to parse like this, this is after taking the photo with the camera.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    byte[] image_byte_array;
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        post_object = new Post();
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        image_byte_array = stream.toByteArray();
        picture_file = new ParseFile("Picture", image_byte_array);
        picture_file.saveInBackground();
        post_object.put("Image", picture_file);
        post_object.saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have a similar code in my proyect, and i save the image of an user on Parse with this and show in a ParseImageView, and it work:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        // put on my imageview
     //   ImagenParseUserNavigation.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
     //   ImagenParseUser.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();


        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        ParseFile photoFile = new ParseFile("fotoperfil"+currentUser.getUsername()+".png",image);

        currentUser.put("Imagen", photoFile);
        currentUser.saveInBackground();
    }

}
```